# Query to discard logical partial matches, SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server

With following table:

```
with cte as (
SELECT '40110 qwerty1' AS Description, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DateIN UNION ALL
SELECT '40199 qwerty2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '402   qwerty3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty4', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 3 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty5', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 4 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty6', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5 UNION ALL
SELECT '40211 qwerty7', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 6 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty8', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 7 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty9', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 8       
)
SELECT DISTINCT A.Description
from cte A
ORDER BY A.Description ASC
```

Giving results:

```
Description
-------------
40110 qwerty1
40199 qwerty2
402   qwerty3
40210 qwerty4
40210 qwerty5
40210 qwerty6
40211 qwerty7
40220 qwerty8
40220 qwerty9

(9 row(s) affected)
```

AND (Same table):

```
with cte as (
SELECT '40110 qwerty1' AS Description, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DateIN UNION ALL
SELECT '40199 qwerty2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '402   qwerty3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty4', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 3 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty5', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 4 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty6', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5 UNION ALL
SELECT '40211 qwerty7', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 6 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty8', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 7 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty9', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 8       
)
--SELECT DISTINCT A.Description
--from cte A
--ORDER BY A.Description ASC
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(B.Description,5) AS Nr
from cte B
ORDER BY LEFT(B.Description,5) ASC
```

Giving results:

```
Nr
-----
40110
40199
402  
40210
40211
40220

(6 row(s) affected)
```

How to I query to retrieve all rows of Description field,
where only 1 logical duplicate partial match (the latest ) will be used
meaning I will receive the same number of rows as the 2:nd query(SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(B.Description,5) AS Nr) 6 rows ,and not 9 rows.

Such as:

```
40110 qwerty1
40199 qwerty2
402   qwerty3
40210 qwerty6
40211 qwerty7
40220 qwerty9
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with mycte as (
SELECT '40110 qwerty1' AS Description, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as DateIN UNION ALL
SELECT '40199 qwerty2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 1 UNION ALL
SELECT '402   qwerty3', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 2 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty4', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 3 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty5', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 4 UNION ALL
SELECT '40210 qwerty6', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5 UNION ALL
SELECT '40211 qwerty7', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 6 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty8', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 7 UNION ALL
SELECT '40220 qwerty9', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 8       
)
SELECT  y.Description, y.DateIN
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.Description, x.DateIN, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LEFT(x.Description,5) ORDER BY x.DateIN DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM    mycte x
) y
WHERE y.RowNum = 1
```

Results:

```
Description   DateIN    
------------- ----------
40110 qwerty1 2013-12-01
40199 qwerty2 2013-12-02
402   qwerty3 2013-12-03
40210 qwerty6 2013-12-06
40211 qwerty7 2013-12-07
40220 qwerty9 2013-12-09
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return a random row, then you can do so using `row_number()`:

```
SELECT b.Description
FROM (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by LEFT(B.Description,5) order by newid()) as seqnum
      from cte b
     ) b
where seqnum = 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

The SQL Fiddle for this is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12421).

Alternatively, you could use aggregation instead and choose `min()` or max()`:

```
SELECT max(B.Description) AS Nr
from cte B
GROUP BY LEFT(B.Description,5) ASC
ORDER BY 1
```